# Continuity on the parameters of the intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a compact metric space (feel free to impose more conditions as long as they're also satisfied by spheres) and $F : X \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that

- $F(x, 0) > 0$ for all $x \in X$
- $F(x, 1) < 0$ for all $x \in X$

Then, for each $x \in X$, let $t_0(x) \in [0, 1]$ be the smallest such that $F(x, t_0(x)) = 0$. Is $t_0 : X \to [0, 1]$ a continuous function?

A friend suggested that I applied the [Maximum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem), but to show that the relevant correspondence is lower semicontinuous I need to prove the following statement:

If $x_n \to x$ and $F(x, t) = 0$, there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ and a sequence $t_k$ such that $F(x_{n_k}, t_k) = 0$ and $t_k \to t$. This doesn't seem very obvious or even true, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ also be some interval, e.g., $[-1,1]$, and let 
$$
F(x,t)=x^2(1-2t)
$$
Then $t(x)=1/2$ for all $x\ne 0$ while $t(0)=0$, thus no continuity at zero.

One can add a slight perturbation so that the set $F(0,t)=0$ is some smaller segment, e.g., $[0.2,0.8]$ and the conditions are also satisfied at $x=0$.